# How to test that a Jar is in a classpath in windows?

Tags: java, windows, classpath

I have the classic :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/util/jython
```

Even if the jar jython.jar exist in the environment variable PATH for my user **and** system wide path.

How can I quickly test that I am not crazy and it is indeed in the path?

Comment: are you using the command prompt or any ide ?

Comment: I am usind a classic command windows (cmd.exe), the java program is launched via a .cmd file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't use the `PATH` variable.

To specify the classpath when running a java application use the `-cp` parameter for the `java` command.

Inside your batch file (the .cmd file) find the `java` command and add the needed jar file:

```
java -cp somefile.jar;\path\to\jython.jar someclass.MainMethod
```

Please don't use the deprecated `CLASSPATH` any more.

For more details, please see the Java documentation: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#tooloption

Answer (score 2):

use the following command

```
set classpath="path to your jar/jython.jar";
```

Comment: Please don't use the deprecated `classpath` variable any more

Comment: What should I use if I do not use this variable?